# How to remove silence part from mp3 that is extracted from tv drama

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3

I hear a mp3 that is extracted from some tv dramas as a English exercise.
So in that mp3 there are lot of "silence part" in which no one speaks and there is no background music.

Is there a way to remove that silence part by using `ffmpeg` or some other program from command line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [SoX - Sound eXchange](http://sox.sourceforge.net/). To remove silence from file:

```
sox input.mp3 output.mp3 silence 1 0.1 1% -1 0.1 1%
```

Also there is a good tutorial: [The SoX of Silence | digitalcardboard.com](http://digitalcardboard.com/blog/2009/08/25/the-sox-of-silence/)

Answer (score -3):

At this point, you're talking about audio editing so you may try looking into `audacity`

Comment: You are suggesting a generic tool for a specific task which can be automated..

Comment: Can it be automated? Nothing in the OP implies that it could be. If anything it's implied that it can't be as most _television dramas_ don't follow a pattern predictable enough to give literal values to a given tool.

Comment: Also it's generally _better_ form to recommend generic tools rather than highly specific ones since the skillset they earn with one tool can be transferred to new problems they may face in the future. Typically you only suggest specialized tools if the generic ones can't quite achieve the effect you're going for.

Comment: With such specific and small tasks as automatically filtering silence out it is better to use something like @diffycat answered with. Your suggestion is good in general, but I think in this case specific tools can solve the problem more efficiently.

Comment: To my way of thinking, both are valid in their own ways. It's not like filtering the silence in `audacity` is really that difficult. You just open the file up, highlight the silent part, delete, and save. Versus using `sox` where yeah this one problem has a solution the OP can copy and paste but things tend to be very manual.

Comment: You missed: “highlight the second silent part, delete, highlight the third silent part, delete, …” There's probably a way to do this in Audacity, but you didn't mention that in your answer. Doing it manually is not reasonable.

Comment: I don't really see why it isn't reasonable. The operation is pretty simple so even doing it 5-10 times shouldn't be a huge issue. Even with 10 gaps, I wouldn't expect to spend more than two minutes doing this. I don't know many people who don't have two minutes out of their day to spare. I guess you could call this doing it manually, but it's also learning a tool they may find useful if they're for some reason interested in sound editing. This one solution has something the OP can copy/paste but they'd still have to learn to do this command line which is even more manual than just using a GUI.